# android:configChanges="${configuration}"

Tags: android, android-manifest, build.gradle, android-configchanges

While looking at an application manifest file, I found an activity with configChanges declared as :

```
android:configChanges="${configuration}"
```

I wasn't aware we could use variables in manifest file. Where should I look for the definition of this variable 'configuration'? I looked in the manifest file and didn't find it. This is a gradle project so I looked in the build.gradle file too, but it wasn't defined there.

When declaring something like this, where am I allowed to provided definition for such variables?

Also, can I override manifest declaration of some values e.g. minSdkVersion by later redefining them somewhere else( like build.gradle for the purpose of declaring separate values for different android versions)?

Comment: Basically, the variables defined in the build.gradle file can be accessed in Manifest file with a $ prefix. Could you please check in both app level gradle and module level gradle once again.

Comment: Thanks! I found it in another gradle which was "apply from: " from build.gradle

Comment: Pls upvote the answer i posted as was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the variables defined in the build.gradle file can be accessed in Manifest file with a $ prefix. please check in both app level gradle and module level gradle once again.